# Would it be possible to detect what other commands the user is writing into the python shell?

Tags: python, shell, input

Here is a basic program I've created:

```
basiclist = ['']
def add(input):
    basiclist.append(input)
    return

def show():
    i = 0
    while (i != len(basiclist)):
        print("basic list " + str(i) + " : " + basiclist[i-1])
    return
```

The user in the python shell imports this code, but then runs xyz(). Without adding code for xyz, is it possible to have xyz() run add()?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your above code is saved in the file `foo.py`.  The user runs `import foo` and then

```py
def xyz():
    foo.add('hello world')
```

Alternatively, the user runs `from foo import add` and then

```py
def xyz():
    add('hello world')
```

Comment: This would work, but I would prefer to have the user not define their own function, and instead just type xyz() and have it run add()

Comment: Then you need to import as `from foo import add as xyz`